# What's the approach to figure out reason for mysql crash?

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb

The database I'm using crashes a lot recently. And I can't find a decent way to dig into the issue. I looked into mysql error log, but don't know how to start.

This happened many times and I've recovered the database several times. But it keeps happening and I want to find out the reason and resolve the cause. I've follow the recovery link, and I've tried to search around the failure message. But couldn't figure it out..

So what will you do to find out the crash cause? Is there a guideline? Really appreciate it.

> 2014-12-08 11:01:52 30924 [Note] InnoDB: Resuming purge
>
> 2014-12-08 11:59:10 7f945e0e3700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140275209877248 in file buf0buf.cc line 3687
>
> InnoDB: Failing assertion: buf_fix_count > 0
>
> InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>
> InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
>
> InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>
> InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
>
> InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>
> InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>
> InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
>
> 19:59:10 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
>
> This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong and this may fail. Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any bugs at http://bugs.percona.com/
>
> key_buffer_size=33554432
>
> read_buffer_size=131072
>
> max_used_connections=6
>
> max_threads=1002
>
> thread_count=3
>
> connection_count=3
>
> It is possible that mysqld could use up to
>
> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 432019 K  bytes of memory
>
> Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0
>
> Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went terribly wrong...
>
> stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x8c821e]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x671f44]
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f98c3646cb0]
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f98c2a9c425]
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b)[0x7f98c2a9fb8b]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa5e1c8]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa754ce]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa766b3]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa5a727]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa3de9c]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9e384d]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9e0b7d]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9e1ecc]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9b299c]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa09f26]
>
> /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9fc62c]
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f98c363ee9a]
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f98c2b59ccd]
>
> You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/. You may find information in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
>
> 141208 11:59:14 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
>
> 141208 11:59:14 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted

Comment: _So what will you do to find out the crash cause?_ - start by __reading the error message carefully__, especially the bit about '__there may be a corruption__ in the InnoDB tablespace'. Then I'd __follow the link__ in the message that points to the reference for sorting this out, and finally I'd __ask questions in the right place__, namely [dba.se] since this isn't a programming issue.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I've create a question in Database Administrator. Sorry about posting in the wrong place.

Comment: I post it here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84655/whats-the-approach-to-figure-out-reason-for-mysql-crash

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known percona bug fixed in 5.6.13-61.0 :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1224432

Comment: hmm... I'm using 5.6.14-62.0, so it should be fixed in my database I guess?

Comment: Looks as if it's not fully fixed then ... maybe you should comment on the bug report that you're still getting the same assertion message?

Comment: I didn't have this issue a couple months ago. This is very recent. I'm not sure if it's the same bug. But it might be a good idea, I'll post there see if I can get any respond.. Thanks